# Simple XML is not working from android device works fine with emulator

Tags: android, simple-framework

So I am using simple xml in my android project and it works fine with emulator but when I use on my device I get this exception

```
07-25 11:52:17.351: I/dalvikvm(2934): Could not find method javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory.newInstance, referenced from method org.simpleframework.xml.stream.StreamProvider.<init>
07-25 11:52:17.351: W/dalvikvm(2934): VFY: unable to resolve static method 6849: Ljavax/xml/stream/XMLInputFactory;.newInstance ()Ljavax/xml/stream/XMLInputFactory;
```

I tried adding the stax api jar and others in dependency but then dalvik wouldn't compile. The funny thing is it all works with emulator with only my simple-xml-2.7.jar in classpath.

Any pointers are greatly appreciated. My android device has Android 4.1.1 on it.

I am converting a java object to xml Here is the object. **Please note** that The code works fine in emulator the error is reported only on actual device with android 4.1.1.

```
@Default
@Namespace(reference="http://bo.myobject")
public class Header implements Serializable
{

    private final static long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Element(required = false)
    protected String xyz;

    public Header() {
        super();
    }

    public Header(final String xyz) {
        this.xyz = xyz;
    }

   getters/setters
}
```

Comment: @mikeyaworski I added the code as you asked however my gut feeling is that something is not right with the dalvik otherwise why would this code works on emulator but not on device? The missing javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory is part of stax api which is supposed to be supplied within android libraries. I tried to add it in libs folder explicitly but dalvik wouldn't compile the code citing namespace issues.

Answer (score 0):

The statement made on this question is incorrect. Your code is working on both your device and on the emulator. The below message has nothing to do with the operation of Simple XML on Android. On Android it uses XML Pull not StAX.

> 07-25 11:52:17.351: I/dalvikvm(2934): Could not find method javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory.newInstance, referenced from method org.simpleframework.xml.stream.StreamProvider.
>
> 07-25 11:52:17.351: W/dalvikvm(2934): VFY: unable to resolve static method 6849: Ljavax/xml/stream/XMLInputFactory;.newInstance ()Ljavax/xml/stream/XMLInputFactory;

You have to ignore this message!